# SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION not changing to 1/60

Tags: android-ndk, android-camera2

I am trying to change SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION from 1/30 to 1/60.
First I have set CONTROL_AE_MODE to CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF.

```
uint8_t aeMode = ACAMERA_CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF;

ACaptureRequest_setEntry_u8(capture_request, ACAMERA_CONTROL_AE_MODE, 1, &aeMode)
```

Then updating sensor frame duration

```
int64_t framedur = 16666666;
ACaptureRequest_setEntry_i64(capture_request, ACAMERA_SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, 1, &framedur)
    
int64_t expTime = 83222;
ACaptureRequest_setEntry_i64(capture_request, ACAMERA_SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, 1, &expTime)
    
int64_t sensitivity = 56;
ACaptureRequest_setEntry_i32(capture_request, ACAMERA_SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 1,  &sensitivity)
```

If I get these values immediately, I get the values which are set recently.
But in onCaptureCompleted callback, SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION is 33323892 and not 16666666.

Can anyone suggest why this can happen.

Comment: Maybe the camera simply doesn't support 60 fps with the given configuration. Have you read the documentation for `ACAMERA_SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION` regarding how to query the minimum frame duration?

Comment: I have queried minimum frame duration and below is the output:
SCALER_AVAILABLE_MIN_FRAME_DURATIONS :  
(35, 1920, 1080, 4166666)
(35, 1440, 1080, 4166666)
(35, 1280, 960, 4166666)
(35, 1280, 720, 4166666)
(35, 720, 480, 4166666)
(35, 640, 480, 4166666)
(35, 320, 240, 4166666)
(35, 176, 144, 4166666)

I did changes and now setting SENSOR_FRMAE_DURATION to 4166666 as per configuration. But still in onCaptureCompleted, I get the value as 33323892.